# Construction Of A Cantor-like set with certain property

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, cantor-set

Is there a way to construct a measurable set $E \subset [0,1]$ with the property that for every interval $[a,b] \subset [0,1]$, both $[a,b]\cap E $ and $[a,b]$\ $E$ have positive Lebesgue measure?

I think you have to construct a cantor set of positive measure and add in each of the intervals that are ommited another cantor like set with positive measure, and continue this procedure indefinitely but I cannot rigorously prove that its correct. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: bof means Spawn should show his own work before commanding us to do this for him.

Comment: $( [a,b] \cap E) \cup ( [a,b] \setminus E) = [a,b]$

Comment: This has to be for every interval [a,b] not just a certain choice.

Comment: I know it is for every interval, I am just giving you an idea. Also, maybe look at the Fat-Cantor Set.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. Not every interval will intersect with positive measure.